# Having issue running node server at host port 80 using nginx proxy + dockergen?

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Basically I am attempting to setup my node app to be served by nginx at `http://192.168.99.100/` of my docker machine instead of by bypassing nginx and doing something like `http://192.168.99.100:7777/` by publishing port 7777 to the host.

I am currently attempting to serve my `frontend` node app container on the root of my docker-machine i.e http://192.168.99.100/ . I am using dockergen together with nginx (separate containers) to have this be automatically generated. My node app which is built from a Dockerfile is run `npm run dev:no-debug` at the following address and port `localhost:7777`.

I have the following compose file.

```
version: '2'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    expose:
      - "7777"
    environment:
      - "PORT=7777"
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=192.169.99.100"
  nginx_proxy:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx_proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - /tmp/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
  dockergen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    container_name: dockergen
    volumes_from:
      - nginx_proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./dockergen/templates:/etc/docker-gen/templates
    entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/docker-gen -notify-sighup nginx_proxy -watch -only-exposed /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

The containers start up fine and are working correctly with no errors.

```
 Name                   Command               State                    Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cms_frontend_1   npm run dev:no-debug             Up      7777/tcp
dockergen        /usr/local/bin/docker-gen  ...   Up
nginx_proxy      nginx -g daemon off;             Up      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

The default.conf nginx file generated with my current settings has:

```
upstream 192.169.99.100 {
      # cms_frontend_1
      server cms_frontend_1:7777;
}
server {
        server_name 192.169.99.100;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.169.99.100;
        }
}
```

When going to `http://192.168.99.100/` i get a 503.

Im still pretty new to world of networking however from the above snippet when a request of 192.169.99.100 is picked up, nginx then uses the upstream block corresponding to the proxy_pass address which then passes this request through to that server ie `cms_frontend_1:7777`?

From this I guess the issue is that the `cms_frontend_1:7777` doesnt correspond to `localhost:7777` which is where the server is running. If i add the following to the `frontend` service container I can then access my app at `http://192.168.99.100:7777`. However this defeats the purpose of having nginx proxy the request.

```
ports:
  - "7777:7777"
```

So my question is this an incorrect configuration or have I made a mistake/misunderstanding about how some concept works? Also I'd like to have this be as dynamic as possible, so say if i wanted to deploy to aws things wouldnt need to be reconfigured all over the place (hence my attempted use of dockergen).

Thanks